# Is there a wordpress theme/plugin for this background-image effect?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for a wordpress theme or plugin that will let me mimic the background image effect found on [this website](http://www.lakeviewproductions.net/#home1). I'm referring specifically to the way the fixed background image changes based on the scroll position. I.e. if you're at the top of the page, the background image is the man at the lockers. If you're at the bottom, the image is of the band.

I know it's possible to do this with javascript, but I'm wondering if there's a theme that incorporates this effect.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a lot of themes out there that have the parallax background scrolling effect: https://themeforest.net/tags/parallax?category=wordpress&referrer=search&utf8=%E2%9C%93&view=list  (these are the results for WP themes with the "parallax" tag)

There are a few plugins as well, such as this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/adamrob-parallax-scroll/

Comment: hopefully this isn't too ignorant a question, but is that what parralax is? My understanding was that parralax was when the background image scrolled at a different rate as the page content.

Comment: No worries. Yes, parallax is where the element background or lower layer scrolls at a different rate as the content. In the case of the example that you provided,  they have a div with the id of "parallax-images" that contains two divs stacked in different places on the page. Each has an actual image element but could easily use background image as well depending on which script is being used.

I achieved something similar on this site: http://chandlerinc.com/about-us/